# Can't stop foreman

Tags: redis, foreman

I have the following Profile that I use with foreman to do development work for a heroku site:

```
web: gunicorn project_name.wsgi -b 0.0.0.0:$PORT
worker: python manage.py rqworker default
redis: redis-server
```

Everything worked great until I added the redis line.  While the app runs fine, I cannot kill foreman with control-c -- it just keeps running.  The only way I can kill foreman is by killing the redis-server process.

How can I get foreman to respond (and stop) to the control-c?

Comment: Tell him he won't get a bonus in december if he doesn't shape up.

Comment: Everyone is a comedian...  ;)

Answer (score 0):

This usually happens because redis or memcached won't shut down.  So I have just created a script that I run to kill the development environment.  Currently it is:

```
#!/bin/bash

redis-cli SHUTDOWN
killall memcached
```